# Null response from salesforce soap api create call

Tags: php, api, soap, salesforce, response

I have inherited some php salesforce api code that is mostly working. The basic task is to sync information between salesforce and a website.

I have a cron job that pulls everything necessary from salesforce, and inserts to the site as expected. It even goes back and updates a custom field in sf to indicate the id in the site table.

However, the opposite is not working. I have a loop that builds a bunch of custom objects from the site's table, but when it sends over to sf as in

```
$response = $client->create($array_objects, 'Custom_Object_Name__c')
```

the response is just NULL. No error message, nothing.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can debug, or why this would happen? I've checked permissions, the logged in user has full permissions on this object.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The php sdk was using the following foreach syntax:

```
foreach($sObjects as &$sObject){
    ...
    $sObject = xx;
}
```

This was not updating the original array object, so nothing was being sent to salesforce. I created a new array and assigned the new objects to the new array, and it works.

I hope this helps someone else.